# Server.MapPath and running a command line utility from an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, windows

I need to run an executable from an ASP.NET app using `Process`. The .exe file is located inside the ASP.NET project - 'ProjectRoot/Utilities/utility.exe'

Why does this code fail to run it:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("/Utilities/");
string args = " etc etc";
Process p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(path + "utility.exe", args));
p.WaitForExit(3000);
```

I've tried `"\\utility.exe"` too.

Comment: Does it run from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the type of the occuring exception. By the way, if the identity of application pool (which is the equal position to the process in a windows app) is set to a limited user (as it is by default) you can not execute a process on the server because of security issues.

If you know about the consequences and the server is your own, you can change the identity of the application pool to an authorized user, then your application can do such a thing without any hesitation.

Cheers

Comment: Doesn't throw an exception :|

Comment: As you said "This code fails to run.". So what does it mean? What happens when you run the process?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things to check here.

The first thing is to ensure that `string path = Server.MapPath("/Utilities/");` is a valid path and that `utility.exe` is in the correct location.

You said that it does not throw an exception, so the invocation of `utility.exe` *should* at least be valid. However, `utility.exe` *may* swallow any exceptions it in turn encounters (depends on how it was coded), which may be why it does not appear to be working.

On top of that, your `args` variable may be specifying a file or some other resource that `utility.exe` accesses. If it does swallow exceptions, it could be masking a permissions error if the application pool identity does not have access to the resouce.